# $x$ is irreducible if and only if $xR$ is maximal amongst all principal proper ideals of $R$. Is this proof missing a key point?

Tags: ring-theory

**Proposition:**  If $R$ is an integral domain and $x\in R\setminus \{0\}$, then $x$ is irreducible if and only if $xR$ is maximal amongst all principal proper ideals of $R$ (ie if $I=yR \subsetneq R$ and $xR\subseteq yR$ then $xR=yR$).

One direction of the
**Proof:**  ($\Rightarrow$)  Suppose $x$ is irreducible and choose $y\in R$ with $xR\subseteq yR\subsetneq R$.  Then, for some $r\in R$, $x=yr$.  Since $x$ is irreducible, either $y\in U(R)$ or $r\in U(R)$.  However, the fact that $yR\neq R$ implies that $y\notin U(R)$, hence $r\in U(R)$, $y=r^{-1}x$, and it easily follows that $xR=yR$.  Hence, $xR$ is maximal amongst proper principal ideals of $R$.

Question: We want to show that $x$ is irreducible implies $xR$ is maximal amongst all principal proper ideas of $R$. But a maximal element of a set is defined to be a member of that set ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements))! So don't we also have to show that $x$ is irreducible implies that $xR$ is in fact a **proper** principal ideal?

The proof above does show: $I=yR \subsetneq R$ and $xR\subseteq yR$ then $xR=yR$.

But isn't there more work to be done for the $\implies$ diection?

Don't we have to show $x$ is irreducible implies $xR \not = R$ as well?
Can you please prove this?

Comment: $xR=R$ iff $x$ is a unit. By definition, an irreducible element is not a unit.

Comment: @Aphelli thanks. And that solves that. Sorry, this stuff is super new to me. Should I just delete my post?

Comment: I personally wouldn’t like that, but I’m not sure what the site policy is.

Comment: just post your comment as an answer then maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m turning my answer into a comment. Given a nonzero ring $R$ and an element $x \in R$, $xR$ is a proper ideal of $R$ iff $x$ isn’t a unit.

But if $R$ is an integral domain and $x \in R$ is irreducible, $x$ is *by definition* not a unit, so that $xR$ is a proper ideal.